# Unix sort of version numbers

Tags: unix, sorting

I have a list of version numbers, let's say for instance that they are in a file versions.txt

```
1.2.100.4
1.2.3.4
10.1.2.3
9.1.2.3
```

I wish to sort them so that they are sorted by version.  i.e:

```
1.2.3.4
1.2.100.4
9.1.2.3    
10.1.2.3
```

I have tried using various sort commands using the "k" parameters, but do not really understand it well enough to pull it off.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: related: compare two version strings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023830/bash-how-compare-two-strings-in-version-format

Answer (score 123):

The `-V` option is the nicest, but I wanted to stay away from installing new/other software since my sort didn’t have that option.

This is the command that worked for me in the end:

```
sort -t. -k 1,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n test.txt
```

From comments:

- To reverse the order: `sort -t. -k 1,1nr -k 2,2nr -k 3,3nr -k 4,4nr`
- To skip the `v` prefix: `sort -t. -k 1.2,1n -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n`

Comment: This is exactly what I would have expected with just -t. -n, as you'd expect each field to be sorted numerically, with like values in a field defer to the next field to the right.  I'd always been frustrated getting sort to behave this way -- its good to know how to do this finally.

Comment: Good question. Good answer. To reverse the order, add some 'r's...
`sort -t. -k 1,1nr -k 2,2nr -k 3,3nr -k 4,4nr`

Comment: If your version numbers start with a "v" (like v2.7.5) then this will let you sort on the second character of the first group: sort -r -t. -k __1.2,1n__ -k 2,2n -k 3,3n -k 4,4n

Comment: Incredible, still useful today :)

Answer (score 114):

```
sort -V versions.txt
```

From `man sort`:

> `-V`, `--version-sort`
> natural sort of (version) numbers within text

See also [Details about version sort](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Version-sort-overview.html#Version-sort-overview).

Comment: Which versions of `sort` have this? My copy of GNU `sort` (on both OS X and Cent OS) doesn't have the `-V` option.

Comment: I'm using Debian Sid, which currently have GNU coreutils 8.5.

Comment: Ah, here it is: http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Details-about-version-sort.html

Comment: The sort -V looks very cool.  Unfortunately the sort installed on this box does not support the -V flag.

Comment: You could install a newest version of sort. What's the OS of this box ? Another solution would be to find a program on the web. Just look for "natural sort". I found at least a PHP script.

Answer (score 5):

BSD does not provide `-V` by default, so Ben's solution is as close as it gets. For your convenience I post here our version that is able to sort files like `<label>-<version>.<ext>`:

```
% ls bla-*.ime | sed -Ee 's/^(.*-)([0-9.]+)(\.ime)$/\2.-1 \1\2\3/'  | sort -t. -n -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4 | cut -d\  -f2-
bla-1.ime
bla-1.0.ime
bla-1.0.0.ime
bla-1.1.ime
bla-1.1.29.ime
bla-1.2.3.ime
bla-1.2.29.ime
bla-1.2.30.ime
bla-1.3.ime
bla-1.3.0.ime
bla-1.3.1.ime
bla-1.3.10.ime
bla-1.3.20.ime
bla-1.7.ime
bla-1.11.29.ime
bla-2.3.2.ime
bla-11.2.2.ime
```

Short explanation:

- List the files that you want to sort with `ls`.
- Find the version number and prefix the line with that.
- While doing that add `-1` to the end to make shorter version number sort first (before `.0` even). You could change `-1` to `0` if you consider `1.3` to be equivalent to `1.3.0`.
- Sort the lines using Ben's suggested solution on the version number.
- Chop off the version prefix from the line.

The list now contains a version sorted list of applicable file names. Any additional sorting on the `label` part is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Actually, BSD does in fact support `-V` by default: https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sort&sektion=1 since at least 2012. I didn't go back into historical versions to see when it was updated, but Apple is just using ancient copies of the BSD tools.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know, but it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This command:

```
echo "1.2.100.4,1.2.3.4,10.1.2.3,9.1.2.3" | tr ',' '\n' | sort -V
```

Gives output:

```
1.2.3.4
1.2.100.4
9.1.2.3
10.1.2.3
```

Comment: This should be more readable:

`1.2.3.4`
`1.2.100.4`
`9.1.2.3`
`10.1.2.3`

Answer (score 0):

In Perl:

```
sub compare_version_numbers {
   my ($l,$r) = @_;
   my @lx = split("\\.",$l);
   my @rx = split("\\.",$r);
   my $minlen = (@lx < @rx) ? @lx : @rx;
   for (my $i=0; $i < $minlen; $i++) {
      # make numeric by multiplying with 1
      my $l_number = ($lx[$i] * 1);
      my $r_number = ($rx[$i] * 1);
      # compare with spaceship operator
      my $l_vs_r = ($l_number <=> $r_number);
      # return if decision is clear!
      if ($l_vs_r != 0) {
         return $l_vs_r
      }
      # otherwise, next part in array of version numbers
   }
   # if we are here, we could not decide - shortest entry wins!
   return @lx <=> @rx
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```
sort -n <versions.txt
```

Comment: No, what he wants is a natural sort, not a numeric sort.

Answer (score -4):

```
echo "1.2.100.4,1.2.3.4,10.1.2.3,9.1.2.3" | tr ',' '\n' | sort -k1,1n
```

Output:

> 1.2.100.4
>   1.2.3.4
>   9.1.2.3
>   10.1.2.3

You should be able to figure out the rest. Good luck

Comment: Why is 100 less than 3 here? Version 1.2.100.4 should come after 1.2.3.4