# Find foldername of highest version

Tags: regex, bash

I've got a few folders

```
src/1.0.0.1/
src/1.0.0.2/
src/1.0.0.12/
src/1.0.0.13/
src/1.0.1.1/
```

I'm looking for a bash command-chain that always returns only the latest version.
In the upper case that would be `1.0.1.1`. If `1.0.1.1` wasn't present the latest version would be `1.0.0.13`

I'm on OS X so sort has no -V option.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use an awk script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

$0 ~ /[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)*\/?$/ {
    t = $0
    sub(/\/$/, "", t)
    sub(/.*\//, "", t)
    current_count = split(t, current_array, /\./)

    is_later = 0

    for (i = 1; i <= current_count || i <= latest_count; ++i) {
        if (current_array[i] > latest_array[i]) {
            is_later = 1
            break
        } else if (latest_array[i] > current_array[i]) {
            break
        }
    }

    if (is_later) {
        latest_string = $0
        latest_count = split(t, latest_array, /\./)
    }
}

END {
    if (latest_count) {
        print latest_string
    }
}
```

Run:

```
find src/ -maxdepth 1 -type d | awk -f script.awk  ## Or
ls -1 src/ | awk -f script.awk
```

You can also use a minimized version:

```
... | awk -- '$0~/[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)*\/?$/{t=$0;sub(/\/$/,"",t);sub(/.*\//,"",t);c=split(t,a,/\./);l=0;for(i=1;i<=c||i<=z;++i){if(a[i]>x[i]){l=1;break}else if(x[i]>a[i])break}if(l){s=$0;z=split(t,x,/\./)}}END{if(z)print s}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `sort` (the `-V` option performs version sort):

```
$ ls -1 src/
1.0.0.1
1.0.0.12
1.0.0.13
1.0.0.2
$ find src/1* -type d | sort -rV
src/1.0.0.13
src/1.0.0.12
src/1.0.0.2
src/1.0.0.1
$ mkdir src/1.0.1.1
$ find src/1* -type d | sort -rV
src/1.0.1.1
src/1.0.0.13
src/1.0.0.12
src/1.0.0.2
src/1.0.0.1
```

Pipe the output to `head` and you can get only the highest version:

```
$ find src/1* -type d | sort -rV | head -1
src/1.0.1.1
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm on OS X so I have no -V option.

Comment: @Hedge Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4495368/2235132) answer that doesn't make use of `-V` option.