# Numerical sort of file names

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a folder with scripts with a name pattern of `UPDATE[x.y.z]` where `x.y.z` is the script's version.

What I need is a bash script that runs the scripts ordered by their version, hence alphabetic sort is not good.

For example `UPDATE1.11.0` should be executed after `UPDATE1.2.3`.

is there a comparator I can use on order to dictate that sorting order? if not, how else can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And if you don't have GNU sort (i.e. you're in OSX or FreeBSD or NetBSD), you may be able to fake it by sorting different fields.

```
[ghoti ~]$ printf "foo1.2.3\nfoo1.11.0\nfoo1.4.1\nfoo1.4.0\n" | sort -nt. -k2,3
foo1.2.3
foo1.4.0
foo1.4.1
foo1.11.0
[ghoti ~]$
```

This misses out on the major version number because it's not delimited by a dot.  But it may work for you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU `sort` or another version that supports it, you can use version sort.

```
sort -V
```

or

```
sort --version-sort
```

Also, in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023830/bash-how-compare-two-strings-in-version-format/4025065#4025065), I posted a script which compares versions.