# Shell script to verify the version of make on linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write this shell script to verify the version of make which is installed on the linux, but unable to get it working. It will be great if someone can point me what I am missing here.

```
OUTPUT="$(make --version | head -1)"
echo "${OUTPUT}" | grep -o '[0-9]*[\.][0-9]*'

OP="$(echo \"${OUTPUT}\" | grep -o '[0-9]*[\.][0-9]*')" 
echo "${OP}"

if [ $OP -ge 3.82 ]; then
  echo "make version is greater than or equal to 3.82"
else:
  echo "make version is not greater than or equal to 3.82"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Off the bat, I see that "op" should be "$op" in the if statement. Also, what happens when you run it now?

Comment: This is the output after the change:
3.82
./test.sh: line 4: =3.82: command not found

./test.sh: line 7: [: -ge: unary operator expected

Comment: You should have only made that change in the if statement, not in the statement where you set the variable.

Comment: My bad, now output is: ./test.sh: line 7: [: 3.82: integer expression expected

Comment: Bash doesn't like floats on it's own. Try `if [[ $(echo $OP '>=' 3.82 | bc -l) -eq 1 ]]`

Comment: `-ge` only compares integers.  `3.82` is not an integer.

Comment: @Sweety: .... or use Zsh instead of bash, which does floating point, for instance `if (( OP >= 3.82 )); then; ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `test` (aka `[`) to compare strings and integers, not versions like that. Here's two questions that show you ways to compare versions:

- [BASH comparing version numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989598/bash-comparing-version-numbers)
- [How compare two strings in dot separated version format in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023830/how-compare-two-strings-in-dot-separated-version-format-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

don't use the char ":" after the key-word else:

```
if [ $OP -ge 3.82 ]; then
  echo "make version is greater than or equal to 3.82"
else
  echo "make version is not greater than or equal to 3.82"
  exit 1
fi
```