# Semver with Bash

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, semantic-versioning

With a bash script, I want to take action if the node version is less than a particular value.

How can I compare semver versions with Bash?

something like:

```
NV=$(node --version)

if [[ ${NV} < 5 ]]; then 
   # do something
fi
```

obvious that's not quite right

`node --version` output just looks like:

```
$ node --version
v6.9.5
```

Comment: How specific do you need the version? 1-7 or do the sub-version releases impact you?

Comment: for the purposes of helping other users, let's do semver major + minor, but ignore patch?

Comment: might as well go all the way and include patch too, dunno

Answer (score 3):

you can use `sort -V` for comparing versions as stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24067243/5348860). a very nice oneliner.

or if you don't mind taking advantage of debian distributions (i'm assuming this premise here), you can:

```
$ dpkg --compare-versions $(node --version | grep -Eo "([0-9]\.)+[0-9]+") lt 5
$ echo $?
$ 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is compare the first digit, you could do this :

```
nv=$(node --version)
if [[ $nv =~ ^v([0-9]+) ]] && (( ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} > 5 )) ; then 
   # do something
fi
```

This code uses the `=~` regex matching operator to match any sequence of numbers following a leading "v", the parentheses allowing the digit sequence to be saved in a sub-expression, and then performing a numerical comparison on that saved sub-expression (found in the `BASH_REMATCH` array at index 1).

Please note that it is generally recommended (though not strictly required) to have variables other than environment variables be lowercase.