# Compare two version numbers (true if different minor version)

Tags: bash, version, string-comparison

I have to compare two version numbers (e. g. `5.6.2` and `5.7.0`) in bash. But the function only has to return `true` if it is a higher or lower minor release number.

#### Examples:

```
| Old Version | New Version | return  |
| ----------- | ----------- | ------- |
|   5.6.2     |   5.7.0     |  true   |
|   5.6.2     |   5.6.9     |  false  |
|   5.6.2     |   5.6.9     |  false  |
|   5.6.2     |   5.5.0     |  true   |
|   5.6.2     |   5.8.8     |  true   |
|   5.6.2     |   6.0.0     |  true   |
|   5.6.2     |   4.0.0     |  true   |
```

Can anyone help me with this? I've tried to edit the function from [BASH comparing version numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16989598/bash-comparing-version-numbers) but I couldn't get it run correctly.

Comment: Please explain the logic. Why is the second example "false"?

Comment: Because it is just a patch update. I need a `true` only if it is a major or minor update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` may help for this case. Here's a simple script to do that,

```
#!/bin/bash

old_version="$1"
new_version="$2"

awk -v u=${old_version} -v v=${new_version} '
BEGIN{ 
  split(u,a,"."); 
  split(v,b,"."); 
  printf "old:%s new:%s => ",u,v; 
  for(i=1;i<=2;i++) if(b[i]!=a[i]){print "true";exit} 
  print "false"
}'
```

The script would only compare major and minor version number, return `false` if they're matched, else return `true`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But your script doesn't work. I always get an syntax error: `syntax error near unexpected token `u,a,"."'`

Comment: Some lines in the script is not pasted successfully, I have corrected it. Please tried again.

Comment: @CWLiu, without speaking to anything else, you need more quotes: `-v u="$old_version" -v v="$new_version"`. Curly brackets do nothing meaningful for correctness here; quotes, by contrast, suppress word-splitting and glob expansion.