# Arithmethic error on bash script

Tags: linux, bash, math, if-statement

I know this is a dumb error, but I could find the solution yet.
I have to compare the apache version. If the apache version is greater than 2.4.3 I have to instal apr in the system before installing apache.
But for some reason I get an arithmetic error in the comparison. 
Basically, I get the apache version and I have to compare it to 2.4.3
This is the test script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

version="2.4.4"
echo "$version"

#if [ '2.4.3' == "$version" ] || [ '2.4.3' < "$version" ]
if [ '2.4.3' -gt '$version' ]

then
        print "Mayor or equal"
else
        print "Error"
fi
```

This is the output:

```
2.4.4
./test9.sh[9]: [: 2.4.3: arithmetic syntax error
Error
```

I would like to know why I can't make the comparison?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [[ '2.4.3' > "$version" ]]
then
    echo  "Mayor or equal"
else
    echo "Error"
fi
```

Comment: Perhaps an explanation of the difference between `[[` and `[`?

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html

Answer (score 2):

Because 2.4.3  in NOT a number, hence you cannot use a NUMERIC comparison.

These are strings, and it's not a good idea to compare versions just like that. For instance:

```
  1.2.3 >= 1.0.0 
  but
  1.2.3 < 1.10.3
```

See the problem?

Answer (score -1):

In this case you could remove the decimals, but it is not a general solution. It would **only** work for your given example and not for version 1.10.5 or even 2.10...

```
 [ 244 -gt ${version//./} ] && echo True
```

If you want something extremely robust (and long) you could use [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023830/bash-how-compare-two-strings-in-version-format) linked in the comments.

Comment: Addressing only a (very) special case is not very useful.

Comment: Well, I expected your objection, but it matches a lot of cases, just not when the versions go beyone 9 and not when there are a variable number of sub-versions. Neither seems to be the case for [apache versions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/). I made it clear this was just for the OPs case, and the robust solution is VERY long, and probably overkill for most uses.