# bash: Issue with comparing function in SunOS 5.10 sun4v

Tags: bash

Hi I tried to use this version compare function provided [compare-two-strings-in-version format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023830/bash-how-compare-two-strings-in-version-format) but I am having problem with SunOS 5.10 sun4v when comparing unequal strings like 1.22 and 1.21
compver.sh: line 55: 10#(1.21) > 10#(1.22): syntax error in expression (error token is "(1.21) > 10#(1.22)")
compver.sh: line 59: 10#(1.21) < 10#(1.22): syntax error in expression (error token is "(1.21) < 10#(1.22)")

This same script works fine in Linux (Linux 2.6.32-431.1.2.el6.x86_64 x86_64).

Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably need Bash or a newer version of it.

Comment: What do you get with `bash --version`?

Comment: Thanks @konsolebox for getting back to me. The version on SunOS is  bash-3.00$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.00.16(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.10)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc. While on the Linux box is GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: Obviously the versions are far apart and sunOS is much older. Do you think upgrading the bash in sunOS will fix it before informing our infrastructure team to do so. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have most versions of Bash installed and I can test your script. Mind updating your post with the crucial part of it?

Comment: Thanks @konsolebox, as I said, I was using the vercomp function provided in another post, see the link above. The offending part in sunOS is given below

Comment: `if ((10#${ver1[i]} > 10#${ver2[i]}))
    then
        return 1
    fi
    if ((10#${ver1[i]} < 10#${ver2[i]}))
    then
        return 2
    fi`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting!

Comment: Just made the test. It doesn't work with Bash 3.0 but works with 3.1.1 and newer versions. So you have to have a newer version of Bash.

Comment: Thanks, I will upgrade to that version or higher and let you know if it works me too.