# How to check version number with letter in it?

Tags: bash, macos

I have a Bash script which compare Versionnumbers. But I need to compare even with a letter in it.

```
ver_a="1.0.0d4"
ver_b="1.0.0d5"

if [[ "$ver_a" -lt "$ver_b" ]]; then
  echo "New Version available!"
fi
```

This sample surely not works. Whats the correct way to process these letter?

Comment: It works if you change `-lt` to `>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare two strings in dot separated version format in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023830/how-to-compare-two-strings-in-dot-separated-version-format-in-bash)

Comment: @oguzismail ... at least if all numbers are single digits or padded to the same width. Otherwise you get `1.9 > 1.10`. For cases like that you can use `sort -V`.

Comment: @Socowi right, a solution using sort -V is available in the linked duplicate