# apply the patches based on openwrt package version

Tags: bash, makefile, package, gnu-make, openwrt

In openwrt, as we known, usually the patches for a certain package should be put in package/[pkg]/patches
and it will be applied in Makefile via $(Build/Patch).
Example:

- package/test/0001-1.0.1.8.fix-A.patch
- package/test/0002-1.0.1.8.fix-B.patch

When the package update to a new version, the patches sometimes also need to be updated.
Example:

- package/test/0001-1.0.1.9.fix-A.patch
- package/test/0002-1.0.1.9.fix-B.patch

OR

- package/test/0001-1.0.2.0.fix-A.patch
- package/test/0002-1.0.2.0.fix-B.patch

For a single certain package version, this works well. The only thing is to update the package version and patches manually.

For a certion reason the old patch can not be applied and submit to package source when pacakge upgrade. So they have to be maintained via patches.

What I am doing is that, if the Makefile could automatically find the right patches based on the package version.
I choose to put all these patches in "package/test/file/patches/" directory base on package verion, such as:

- package/test/file/patches/1.0.1.8/0001-v1.0.1.8.fix-A.patch
- package/test/file/patches/1.0.1.8/0002-1.0.1.8.fix-B.patch
- package/test/file/patches/1.0.1.9/0001-1.0.1.9.fix-A.patch
- package/test/file/patches/1.0.1.9/0002-1.0.1.9.fix-B.patch
- package/test/file/patches/1.0.2.0/0001-1.0.2.0.fix-A.patch
- package/test/file/patches/1.0.2.0/0002-1.0.2.0.fix-B.patch

In the Makefile, the right patches should be copied to "package/test/patches/" directory first in "define Build/Prepare" section, before $(Build/Patch).

Match rule: (I don't know how to insert a table here, I put an image instead ...)

[match the latest version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQVHy.png)

So, in this way, all the patches can be stored in the "pacakge/test" directory and they will be auto matched and applied when building.

The question is , how can I achieve to **find out the right match**?
Since it's a little complex to compare and match the version, especially in **Makefile** rather than in shell script.

Actually I found some interesting script to do part of this, such as：

[how-to-compare-two-strings-in-dot-separated-version-format-in-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023830/how-to-compare-two-strings-in-dot-separated-version-format-in-bash)

Answer (score 1):

While I don't exactly understand which version number you want to compare to which patch or the other way around, the following snippet will give you an idea how solve the task with `GNUmake` programming with the help of [the GNUmake table toolkit](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) which was designed for such problems:

```
include gmtt/gmtt.mk

# Helper function which converts a list of numbers into a decimal
# number with 3 digits per original version place:
vers-to-num = $(call lpad,$(word 1,$1),3,0)$(call lpad,$(word 3,$1),3,0)$(call lpad,$(word 5,$1),3,0)$(call lpad,$(word 7,$1),3,0)

VERSION := 1.1.1.4
VERS_LIST := $(call glob-match,$(word 1,$(VERSION)),*.*.*.*)
$(info VERS_LIST = $(VERS_LIST))

VERS_NUM := $(call vers-to-num,$(VERS_LIST))
$(info $(VERS_NUM))


PATCH := 1.0.2.0


# Patch to version relation:
# Table with 3 columns: patch-nr | first applicable version | last applicable version
# In case there is only one version it has to go into both columns (no empty cells!)
define PATCH_TO_VER :=
3
1.0.1.8   1.0.1.8   1.0.1.8
1.0.1.9   1.0.1.9   1.0.1.9
1.0.2.0   1.0.2.0   1.1.1.3
1.1.1.4   1.1.1.4   1.1.3.9
endef

VA_VB := $(call select,2 3,$(PATCH_TO_VER),$$(call str-eq,$(PATCH),$$1))
$(info VA_VB = $(VA_VB))

VA_LIST := $(call glob-match,$(word 1,$(VA_VB)),*.*.*.*)
VA_NUM := $(call vers-to-num,$(VA_LIST))
$(info $(VA_NUM))

VB_LIST := $(call glob-match,$(word 2,$(VA_VB)),*.*.*.*)
VB_NUM := $(call vers-to-num,$(VB_LIST))
$(info $(VB_NUM))

# Instead of comparing each version digit against upper and lower
# allowed value (the if-else tree for this gets hellish, try it
# yourself) we use gmtt's numeric range capability of at least 64
# digits to compare versions :
COMPARE_RESULT := $(if $(call int-ge,$(VERS_NUM),$(VA_NUM)),$(if $(call int-le,$(VERS_NUM),$(VB_NUM)),yes))

$(info patch version in range (empty=no): <$(COMPARE_RESULT)>)
```

Output:

```
VERS_LIST =  1 . 1 . 1 . 4
001001001004
VA_VB = 1.0.2.0 1.1.1.3
001000002000
001001001003
patch version in range (empty=no): <>
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

Comment: This is based on gmtt/gmtt.mk
Does it aviable in every openwrt project and how I install it ? 
What if I don't have gmtt.

Comment: Actuall I have write some in Makefile and acchieve part of this.

#part-A : compare version such as a.b.c.d, return YES if ge
version_greater_equal = $(shell if printf '%s\n%s\n' '$(2)' '$(1)' | \
      sort -Ct. -k1,1n -k2,2n -k3,3n -k4,4n ; then echo YES; else echo NO; fi)

#part-B: get the subfolder name and each one is such as 
SUB_DIR_LISTS := $(foreach eachdir, $(filter %/, $(wildcard
    ./files/patches/*/)), $(shell echo ${eachdir} | cut -d/ -f4))

Comment: sorry ... I failed to  insert code as format required ....

Comment: @RobertHu No need to install gmtt, just download it from github and put it aside your makefile or whereever you see it fit. It is a simple `include`able makefile.