# how to sort number string such as a.b.c.d in Makefile

Tags: shell, sorting, makefile, gnu-make

The list is such as:

```
list_unsort  =  v50.0.56.8  v50.0.91.19  v50.0.91.9  v50.0.90.0  v50.0.56.18  v50.0.191.9  v37.4.5.8
```

try to sort this list

```
list_sort := $(sort $list_unsort)
```

Result

```
list_sort    = v37.4.5.8 v50.0.191.9 v50.0.56.18 v50.0.56.8 v50.0.90.0 v50.0.91.19 v50.0.91.9
```

As seen, v50.0.56.18 should be sort behind v50.0.56.8.
How to sort correct with an easy way?
This is in Makefile.

Comment: There is no easy way to do it.  GNU make's `sort` function is a lexical sort, not a numeric sort, and there's no facility for numeric sorting or even numeric comparison in GNU make.  You'll have to do it in a shell script, and even there it's not trivial.

Comment: @MadScientist I answered (the same question from the same poster more or less) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62650114/apply-the-patches-based-on-openwrt-package-version/62653464#62653464) but the solution seemed to scare him/her away ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you also have GNU sort available, you can use its `-V` option to sort the way you want:

Example Makefile:

```
list_unsort  =  v50.0.56.8  v50.0.91.19  v50.0.91.9  v50.0.90.0  v50.0.56.18  v50.0.191.9  v37.4.5.8

example:
    @echo $(shell printf "%s\n" $(list_unsort) | sort -V)
```

And demonstration:

```
$ make -f example.mk
v37.4.5.8 v50.0.56.8 v50.0.56.18 v50.0.90.0 v50.0.91.9 v50.0.91.19 v50.0.191.9
```

Comment: Please do not use `shell` functions inside recipes.  It may work in many situations but it's a time-bomb waiting for the unwary.  A recipe is _already_ run in a shell, so there's no need to use make's `shell` function.

Comment: A simpler way to write this is `@printf '%s\n' $(list_unsort) | sort -V`

Comment: @MadScientist Based on OP's question, they're wanting to set a variable, so that wouldn't work. The important part is the function, not the printing of its output for demonstration purposes.

Comment: In that case it would be better to set a variable in your example...?  Then it would be immediately applicable and wouldn't showcase non-recommended methods like using `shell` in a recipe...

Comment: @MadScientist The OP has been asking the same thing, in 4 separate questions, more or less since May. This starts to look like trolling.

Comment: 4th time's the charm! :)