# Bash - define a variable value with sed and extract with if condition

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have been struggling to define a variable value with sed, compare the value to "6.7" and then write to a file.

The value is a version so it's always an int or a double. However my code doesn't seem to work:

```
FILE="user/gradle-6.7-new"
VERSION=$(sed -n '/^distributionUrl=/s/.*gradle-\([^-]*\)-.*/\1/p' $FILE)
if [[ $VERSION > 6.7 ]]
then
  $VERSION > /tmp/version_file
fi
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you add the line which contains the version in the file ?

Comment: @Fravadona it's the `$FILE` variable

Comment: Check out your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/, you'll see the reason

Comment: @Fravadona `Tips depend on target shell and yours is unknown. Add a shebang or a 'shell' directive.` and `^-- SC2072 (error): Decimals are not supported. Either use integers only, or use bc or awk to compare.` I don't think it's relevant to me. Can you suggest a change if you see something wrong?

Comment: What does contain `"$VERSION"`?

Comment: `$VERSION` value is 6.7

Comment: bash only does integer arithmetic. Besides, the `>` inside `[[...]]` is **not** an arithmetic operator.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Is there any way in bash that I can compare versions?

Comment: Yes, but not trivially. You may want to read [How to compare two strings in dot separated version format in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023830/how-to-compare-two-strings-in-dot-separated-version-format-in-bash)

Comment: Comparing versions requires a few lines of code

Comment: Bash, sh or shell? Please read the descriptions of the according tags!

Comment: This: "`$VERSION > /tmp/version_file`" does not write the value of `$VERSION` to `/tmp/version_file`, except possibly under very special circumstances.

Comment: You should use `awk` for this, rather than a combination of shell and `sed`.

Comment: @chepner Can you please send an example?

Answer (score 0):

`awk` may be an easier approach.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
FILE="user/gradle-6.7-new"
awk -F- '{version=$2} version >= 6.7 { print version > "/tmp/version_file" }' <<< $FILE
```

Comment: Thanks. The if statement seems to not be working though. nothing is being written into `/tmp/version_file`

Comment: Real problem is not with the `sed` command. The OP wants to check if `$VERSION` (which can be something like `6.9.8`) greater than `6.7`.

Comment: @HatLess yes I also tested locally. 
@M.NejatAydin I am okay also with only "one dot version compare" like `6.7` and `6.9`. But this doesnt work for mw I tried with `FILE="user/gradle-6.9-new"` I expect `6.9` to be printed into /tmp/version_file but nothing gets is in there

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Thanks, I totally missed that

Comment: @HatLess the output I get now is `6.7/tmp/version_file`

Comment: @I.zv That would imply you removed the redirect `>` from the print statement?

Comment: @HatLess I literally copy and pasted your answer. Could you share what you run and get locally?

Comment: @I.zv `awk -F- '{version=$2} version >= 6.7 { print version > "/tmp/version_file" }' <<< $FILE`  `cat /tmp/version_file`
`6.7`

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- OP's current code properly populates `VERSION` (ie, I'm assuming OP is not having problems populating `VERSION` from `$FILE`)

I'd recommend reviewing the answers @ [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4023830).

While not chosen as the *accepted* answer, a variation on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47897019) is relatively straight forward, ie, let `sort/-V` order the two version strings to be compared and then test the first (or last) line of the `sort/-V` output accordingly, eg:

```
testVERSION='6.7'

for VERSION in 6.6 6.7 6.7.0 6.7.1 6.71
do
    op='<'
    if [[ $(printf "%s\n%s\n" "${testVERSION}" "${VERSION}" | sort -V | head -1) == "${testVERSION}" ]]
    then
        op='='    # at this point we know ${VERSION} >= ${testVERSION}, but assuming OP needs to distinguish between '>=' and '>' we need one more test ...

        [[ "${VERSION}" != "${testVERSION}" ]] && op='>'
    fi
    echo "${VERSION} ${op} ${testVERSION}"
done
```

This generates:

```
6.6 < 6.7
6.7 = 6.7
6.7.0 > 6.7
6.7.1 > 6.7
6.71 > 6.7
```

From here OP should be able to adapt the logic to generate the desired result, eg:

```
testVERSION='6.7'

[[ $(printf "%s\n%s\n" "${testVERSION}" "${VERSION}" | sort -V | head -1) == "${testVERSION}" ]] &&
[[ "${VERSION}" != "${testVERSION}" ]] &&
echo "$VERSION" > /tmp/version_file           # we get this far if ${VERSION} > ${testVERSION}
```