# execute a system() method in awk if a condition matches

Tags: awk

I am trying to check if the gcc version and based on the result
execute another system call (`scl enable devtoolset-7 bash`).

Below is what I have tried so far

```
gcc --version | awk '/gcc/ && ($3+0)<7.0{print "Current Version",$3,"is less than 7.5" system("scl enable devtoolset-7 bash")}'
```

I wish to know how to get this done correctly in awk. Also, I am open to other simpler approaches to do the above, if any.

Comment: Wat do you want to compare?

Comment: I wish to compare the gcc version of the current system against 7.0

Comment: Do you need 'less' than or 'larger' than? Then you'll need [to compare the versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023830/how-to-compare-two-strings-in-dot-separated-version-format-in-bash), otherwise you can just use `!=`

Comment: I need 'less' than. If the gcc version is less, then I need to execute the command ```scl enable devtoolset-7 bash``` as shown above

Comment: You'll need a semicolon (or newline) between the print statement and the system call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't complicate things by having awk spawn a subshell to call another command if you don't have to:

```
if [[ gcc --version | awk '/gcc/ && ($3+0)<7.0{print "Current Version",$3,"is less than 7.5"; f=1} END{exit !f}' >&2 ]]; then
    scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
fi
```

Note that your test is <7.0 but message says <7.5. You might want to make it this instead to ensure consistency:

```
if [[ gcc --version | awk -v minVer='7.0' '/gcc/ && ($3+0)<(minVer+0){print "Current Version",$3,"is less than",minVer; f=1} END{exit !f}' >&2 ]]; then
    scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
fi
```

In general software versions can't be directly compared as either strings or numbers, though, so you might have to think about your comparison. e.g. if you wanted to compare `1.2.3` vs `1.2.4` both would be truncated to `1.2` in a numeric comparison and declared equal, but if you wanted to compare 2 different versions like `12.3` vs `5.7`, the `5.7` would be considered larger in a string comparison.